# "like many others" indicates/points to which part of the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, terminology, phrase-meaning

In the following sentence-

> As I love to read, like many others, a desire for writing grew inside me.

the part **"like many others"** indicates/points to which part of the sentence? **i.e.** to **"As I love to read"** or to **"a desire for writing grew inside me"** ?

So, does it mean

> As I love to read like many others

or

> like many others a desire for writing grew inside me

One more question: Is **"like many others"** a phrase? If not, what's the appropriate term for such group of words?

Comment: In this sentence, _"like many others"_ refers to _"as I love to read"_

Comment: Its ambiguity is not helped by the apparent mismatch in tenses (As I love ... a desire grew). Can you provide more context or a link to where it comes from? Ambiguity is often resolved by referring to context.

Comment: Yes. I'd guess that it's incorrect attempt at 'As I love to read, a desire for writing has grown within me – as has happened with many others.'

Comment: If you are an English-language ***learner***, you might enjoy our sister-site for [ell.se]. That’s because our sister-site is a Q&A site **especially made for *learners***, in contrast to the current English Language and Usage site, which is instead “a Q&A site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Like many others" here actually refers to both characteristics: "like many others who *love to read*, a *desire to write* grew inside me *too*".

The "like many others" here is a rationale, of sorts. It's building up a modus ponens:

> 1) Those people who read a lot often develop a desire to write ("*as everyone knows*").
>
> 2) I, myself, read a lot.
>
> ∴  I developed a desire to write.

In other words, "like many others" is asserting that "those who love to read often come to write" is common knowledge, and in a sense explains, or justifies, the author's decision to become a writer.